# Sharepoint Workflow Task List Title URL

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I am fairly new to SharePoint 2010 Development. I have created a Task Tray Web Part to list all the tasks (from Workflow Tasks List) awaiting action by the currently logged in user. It is required that when the user clicks on a task on the web part, the associated Infopath form  opens for action. I cannot retrieve the URL behind the "Title" Column of the Workflow Task List. Can you show me how to retrieve the URL behind the Title Column of a Workflow Task List in code? C#,VB.Net or JavaScript? Is there another way of achieving this? Thank you.

Comment: The Edit column (data type - Computed) appears to contain the same URL. how can I extract the URL from that column? listitem["Edit"].toString() returns an empty string.

Comment: If there is no way of achieving this, then I suspect I can as well save the url I sent via email which does the same thing. I was hoping to be able to get this information since I can already see it in the URL of the Workflow Tasks List.

Comment: Still Open to any ideas. Maybe there is something I am missing?

Answer (score -1):

I kind of took my second advice/comment. I wrote a function that generates the required URL. Using this, I can now call any workflow list item. If I ever find a way to solve the original challenge, I'll be sure to post it here.